# Adding uncertainty bars on barplot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart

I have the following plot:

```
y = [-2.75 -2.91; -0.48 -0.44];
X = categorical({'AWS1','AWS2'});
bar(X,y)
set(gca, 'fontsize', 14);
ylim([-3 1])
box on
grid on
```

How can I add an uncertainty bar around the blue bars only (-2.75 +/- 0.22 and -0.48 +/- 0.68)?

Thanks!

Comment: In R2019b and later, use [XEndpoints](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.bar-properties.html#mw_3d0c5b61-b082-4c79-b9c6-a21152ae26ff)

Comment: @XZhang That gives you the coordinates of the end points of the bars, it doesn’t add error bars.

Comment: Ah yes, that and [errorbar](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/errorbar.html)